# How to display the Test Result trend in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, test-results

I use the option "Publish xUnit test result report" and it loads my `*.xml`.

I thought that would be enough to display the Test Result trend (the graphics) but it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

Comment: That should be enough to display the trend. I believe it is displayed after you has run the job at least twice. Is the job building successfully?

Comment: only once... will try to run few successful and let you know what happen (probably tomorrow morning) thx for the answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the test trend results to appear at least 2 builds must run first

Comment: And note that if you delete any build, any build before the deleted one is also ignored.   (The the splendid “Warnings Trend” graph doesn’t have this bug.)

Answer (score 2):

under Post build actions, please select **"Publish Junit test build report".**

But make sure that you have used the correct path for "Workspace".

Answer (score 1):

To get the resulting trend of Jenkins's job execution you just go into your project and click on the hyperlink trend which would be available just after build history. By doing this, you will get the result of the last 20 or 30 days which is again configurable. To get trend results of the last 30 days just go to the job configuration and set keep results as 30 days.